# How do I upload multiple pictures at once to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, images, gallery, share-menu

Gallery seems to lack the ability to upload to Facebook when multiple pictures are selected.

Is there easy way to upload a bunch of photos at once to Facebook or is it something that you have to do one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [FriendCaster for Facebook](https://market.android.com/details?id=uk.co.senab.blueNotifyFree) app. This has a feature to upload multiple pictures from Gallery.

Comment: That works, I dislike allowing third party apps control of my accounts, but it can't be helped in this case.